Renders won't work on certain frames
I don't know what happened, but for no reason my Blender project stopped rendering anything past frame 50 or so.
I haven't changed any settings prior to it breaking, it just doesn't work on this specific project. I restarted Blender, but that didn't fix anything.


Hi Kell. This is a site run by volunteers answering question for free on their spare time, rushing them or giving deadlines may be discouraging and is generally considered rude. Among other factors, how fast you get answers depends largely on how thorough your question is. Instead of digressing about deadlines provide factual details to diagnose the issue, add images or GIFs, state what you have tried and what research you did about it. Otherwise may be best to seek professional help.

My apologies, I'm a bit panicked is all. Like I said, I only have 3 days to finish this, or else I fail an entire class that I have now spent about a year on.

Your question (which actually doesn't contain any question) is way too broad and unclear. Nobody will find your issue with no informations. Your best bet would be to reduce to blend file until it fits blend-exchange, while keeping the bug. You may even find the source of the problem along the way.

Disable Sequencer in Output tab > Post Processing ? You have 2 png sequences (which looks empty) and part of your edit doesn't contain anything (so doesn't render anything).

@Lutzi sounds like an answer to me. Care to post it below as such?
